# Mocking a tcp server using a PCAP file in python

Tags: python, mocking, pcap

I have python code that will connect to a server and continuously retrieve data for storing/setting. I used TCP dump to capture what normal traffic looks like and I want to mock this test server for unit testing.

Does anyone know how to mock a TCP server using a pcap file of normal traffic in python?

Comment: I don't think that is the way to go to mock a service.

Comment: After diving more into it, I think you're right. I may have been a little greedy. It will probably be easier to just mock the socket for one way at a time instead of trying to do it all at once. thanks